# how to remove some permissions from a shop "manager role" in woocommmerce?

Tags: user-roles, woocommerce-offtopic, permissions

well, I'm using woo-commerce plugin to manage a shop. I need to add a user who can manage products(add new, edit). so I added a user and gave him a shop manager role, but the permissions granted for this role is much more than what I wanted (e.g. listing other users, accessing orders, being able to change shop's setting and ...).

And I can't figure out how WordPress is managing roles and permissions and in which PHP file woo-commerce is defining this role so that I can edit it.

Comment: This is treading the line of "Off-Topic" since it *does* deal with Third Party Plugins ( WooCommerce ) but the core of your question deals with user permissions. I suggest Editing your question to be more ask the more specific question of "How do I change permission of a specific role" so that the question does not get closed. Another fine option is to search this site for managing user permissions.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I see how you mean this is off topic but I found a tag for woocommerce and just thought related questions are on topic,

Answer (score 3):

This is treading very close to being off-topic as it asks specifically about a particular plugin, but the answer is quite generic:

[You can remove the capabilities you don't need.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap)

```
function remove_cap_wpse_186316(){   
  remove_cap( 'yourwoorole', 'yourwoocap' );
  remove_cap( 'yourwoorole', 'yourwoocap1' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_cap_wpse_186316' );
```

The above is code is for demonstration/experimentation only. Note the note in the codex about this needing to only run once:

> Note: This setting is saved to the database (in table wp_options,
>   field 'wp_user_roles'), so you should run this only once, on
>   theme/plugin activation and/or deactivation.

You can use [`get_role()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_role) and dump the output to see what capabilities you are dealing with:

```
var_dump(get_role( 'yourwoorole' ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add the following code to the functions.php of your wordpress theme. And change the true to false for the following you don't need to provide access for shopmanger.

```
 add_role('shop_manager', __('Shop Manager', 'woocommerce'), array(
    
    'read' => true,
    
    'read_private_pages'    => true,
    
    'read_private_posts'    => true,
    
    'edit_posts' => true,
    
    'edit_pages' => true,
    
    'edit_published_posts'  => true,
    
    'edit_published_pages'  => true,
    
    'edit_private_pages'    => true,
    
    'edit_private_posts'    => true,
    
    'edit_others_posts' => true,
    
    'edit_others_pages' => true,
    
    'publish_posts' => true,
    
    'publish_pages' => true,
    
    'delete_posts' => true,
    
    'delete_pages' => true,
    
    'delete_private_pages'  => true,
    
    'delete_private_posts'  => true,
    
    'delete_published_pages'    => true,
    
    'delete_published_posts'    => true,
    
    'delete_others_posts' => true,
    
    'delete_others_pages' => true,
    
    'manage_categories' => true,
    
    'manage_links'  => true,
    
    'moderate_comments' => true,
    
    'unfiltered_html'   => true,
    
    ‘upload_files’  => true,
    
    ‘export’    => true,
    
    ‘import’    => true,
    
    ‘manage_woocommerce’    => true,
    
    'manage_woocommerce_orders' => true,
    
    'manage_woocommerce_coupons'    => true,
    
    'manage_woocommerce_products'   => true,
    
    'view_woocommerce_reports'  => true
    
    ));
```

Comment: please dont use curly quotes in code